Required lua module not found
When I try to require math-util.lua in my markdown.lua file, error occurs:
Error detected while processing :source (no file):                                                                                                            
E5108: Error executing lua [string ":source (no file)"]:8: module 'snippets.math-util' not found:                                                                     
no field package.preload['snippets.math-util']                                                                                                        
cache_loader: module snippets.math-util not found                                                                                                             
cache_loader_lib: module snippets.math-util not found                                                                                                                 
no file '.\snippets\math-util.lua'                                                                                                                            
no file 'C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\bin\lua\snippets\math-util.lua'                                                                                           
no file 'C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\bin\lua\snippets\math-util\init.lua'                                                                                      
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\snippets\math-util.luac'                                                                                          
no file 'C:\Users\joene\AppData\Local\nvim-data/lazy-rocks/nvim-dap-python/share/lua/5.1/snippets\math-util.lua'                                              
no file 'C:\Users\joene\AppData\Local\nvim-data/lazy-rocks/nvim-dap-python/share/lua/5.1/snippets\math-util/init.lua'                                         
no file 'C:\Users\joene\AppData\Local\nvim-data/lazy-rocks/telescope.nvim/share/lua/5.1/snippets\math-util.lua'                                               
no file 'C:\Users\joene\AppData\Local\nvim-data/lazy-rocks/telescope.nvim/share/lua/5.1/snippets\math-util/init.lua'                                          
no file 'C:/Users/joene/AppData/Local/nvim/snippets/snippets\math-util.lua'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
no file '.\snippets\math-util.lua'                                                                                                                            
no file 'C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\bin\lua\snippets\math-util.lua'                                                                                           
no file 'C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\bin\lua\snippets\math-util\init.lua'                                                                                      
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\snippets\math-util.luac'                                                                                          
no file 'C:\Users\joene\AppData\Local\nvim-data/lazy-rocks/nvim-dap-python/share/lua/5.1/snippets\math-util.lua'                                              
no file 'C:\Users\joene\AppData\Local\nvim-data/lazy-rocks/nvim-dap-python/share/lua/5.1/snippets\math-util/init.lua'                                         
no file 'C:\Users\joene\AppData\Local\nvim-data/lazy-rocks/telescope.nvim/share/lua/5.1/snippets\math-util.lua'                                               
no file 'C:\Users\joene\AppData\Local\nvim-data/lazy-rocks/telescope.nvim/share/lua/5.1/snippets\math-util/init.lua'                                          
no file 'C:/Users/joene/AppData/Local/nvim/snippets/snippets\math-util.lua'                                                                                                                                                                      
no file 'C:/Users/joene/AppData/Local/nvim/sni

Code from markdown.lua that throws the error:
local is_math_mode = require('snippets.math-util')

File paths:
nvim/snippets/markdown.lua
nvim/snippets/math-util.lua

I tried to update package.path with this line, but it did not fix the issue:
package.path = package.path .. ';' .. 'C:/Users/joene/AppData/Local/nvim/snippets/?.lua'

package.path:
;.\?.lua;C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\bin\lua\?.lua;C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\bin\lua\?\init.lua;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\?.luac;C:\Users\joene\AppData\Local\nvim-data/lazy-rocks/nvim-dap-python/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;C:\Users\joene\AppData\Local\nvim-data/lazy-rocks/nvim-dap-python/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;;C:\Users\joene\AppData\Local\nvim-data/lazy-rocks/telescope.nvim/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;C:\Users\joene\AppData\Local\nvim-data/lazy-rocks/telescope.nvim/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;;C:/Users/joene/AppData/Local/nvim/snippets/?.lua

I also created an init.lua in the same directory, which supposedly should make Lua recognize the snippets folder as a module. Did not work.
Also, I am using WindowsPowershell.

Try local is_math_mode = require 'nvim.snippets.math-util'.
